# Can a version of Python's shelve module that knows when its entries have been modified be written in any programming language?

Tags: programming-languages, python, pointers, persistence

`shelve` is a Python module that makes it easy to persist a Python dictionary to disk (under the right conditions).

The [documentation for shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) gives this example to demonstrate one of the pitfalls of using a shelf:

```
import shelve

d = shelve.open(filename)

# ...snip...

# as d was opened WITHOUT writeback=True, beware:
d['xx'] = range(4)  # this works as expected, but...
d['xx'].append(5)   # *this doesn't!* -- d['xx'] is STILL range(4)!
```

The documentation explains:

> Because of Python semantics, a shelf cannot know when a mutable persistent-dictionary entry is modified. By default modified objects are written only when assigned to the shelf (see Example).

To say that shelves behave this way "because of Python semantics" seems to me to be measuring Python via a high bar! It would be hard to for shelve to know whether any object contained in a shelf has a reference to something which has been mutated (or a reference to something that has a reference to something that has been mutated). Can this be done in any programming language?

Comment: @gnat: It's perfectly clear what he's asking: Does any language exist in which it's possible to answer the question "has this object been mutated since [event] happened" in the general case?

Comment: @MasonWheeler unclear what help they need, what problem is answering this expected to solve

Comment: @MasonWheeler: mere curiosity makes this too broad, in my opinion. Questions asking for lists of examples do not fit the format of the Q&A model.

Comment: @Martjin: Seriously?  Does this look *anything like* a list question to you?

Comment: I have a feeling that this question can have an answer more than a list.  I unfortunately don't understand python well enough to find a way to improve this.  If somebody can find a good way to edit this question then please do.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not just a Python problem.

Resolving the question of "has this object been modified since X happened?" (in this case, the object being added to the dictionary) would require one of two things.  Either you use immutable objects, in which case the answer is always "no" and the question is rather meaningless, or you have some way to note when an object is changed in any way.

As far as I know, no language does this automatically.  The .NET framework has a concept of "observable properties" that raise an event when the property is modified, but they have to be implemented manually, and they will only work for properties on the object itself.  (If the object has a sub-object that gets modified, this would change the parent object's serialized representation too.)  So no; this may be an issue "because of Python semantics" but it's because of object-oriented semantics in general.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly doable, even in Python.  The trick is in returning a wrapper instead of the original stored object.

in your example:

```
d['xx'] = range(4)
d['xx'].append(5)
```

the second line can be extended into a retrieve and an operation:

```
d['xx'] = range(4)
t = d['xx']
t.append(5)
```

and it's obvious that `t` doesn't notify `d` about the `.append()` operation.

but if you return an object wrapper `w` that keeps a reference to `d` and the `'xx'` key, it could follow any operation with the appropriate notification.

something like (untested!):

```
class wrapper():
  def __init__(self, container, key):
    self.container = container
    self.key = key
    self.value = container[key]

  def __getattr__(self, name):
    attr = getattr(self.value, name)
    if hasattr(attr, '__call__'):     # is callable?
      def f(*args, **kwargs):
        rv = attr(*args, **kwargs)   # do the call
        self.container[self.key] = self.value    # re-store the (modified?) value)
      return f
    return attr
```

Comment: The wrapper will not have all the semantics of the original object, and can't just be blindly inserted where the original object was.  It also doesn't recurse - say, if `t[0]` was an object and it was the thing that was changed

Comment: right, the whole wrapper implementation is more complex, but among the same line of what i've drafted here.  I guess the `mock` library is a good example of how to do a wrapper that can fool most other code, including the recursive case.

Comment: So, what, you're suggesting a custom wrapper for every type of object that could be added to shelve?  That _definitely_ wouldn't fit into a generic library